# Java for-loop to the power

Tags: java, for-loop

```
import static java.lang.Math.pow;

class projectThreeQ2{
 public static void main (String args[]){

 //Q2: Write a for statement to compute the sum 1 + 2^2 + 32 + 42 + 52 + ... + n2.

 int n = 7;
 int sum = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
   sum = sum + (int)Math.pow(n,2);
 }

 System.out.println(sum);
}
}
```

The question is to make a for-loop to the sum of the n^2.

So in my case;
1
4
9
16
25
36.
Which is equal to 91. However, when I run my code I get 343. Why?

Comment: Math.pow(i,2)   ...

Comment: you have a grand total of 3 variables. run your code step by step and look at the value of each variable at each step, and at the value of the argument of each function.

Comment: NB you don't need to cast to int if you just use `i*i` instead of `Math.pow(i, 2)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using the wrong variable inside the `for`-loop. You use `n` instead of `i`. The correct code is:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    sum = sum + (int)Math.pow(i,2);
}
```

Edited because the loop should run from 1 to n (inclusive) according to the question statement.

Comment: @Kasper you should also start iterating from 1. Check out my answer, cheers!

Comment: @WojciechKazior Mathematical there is no compelling reason to start with 1. It will lead to the same sum. So why _should_ he start from 1?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose he do not have to but he should. In addition he have to end on 'n' - not 'n-1'.

Comment: Well ... In fact you are right. According to the question statement itself he should sum up the squares from 1 to n (both inclusively). But I asked you to tell the reason, not to only say that he _should_. Always give a reason! I edited my answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

You are using n instead of i

```
      sum = sum + (int)Math.pow(i,2);
```

And one more thing, as you use import static , no need for Math.pow, just use pow otherwise remove the import

Answer (score 0):

The one you should power is `i` - not `n`. In addition `i` should start from 1 and end on `n`. So the loop should look like:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    sum = sum + (int)Math.pow(i,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

sum = sum + (int)Math.pow(***i***,2);